# I can't write in binary file from function

Tags: c, file, binary, fwrite, fread

I want to write some data in binary file from recursive function, but I can't. Function should create tree and write its nodes in file on specific address.
Arguments of function:
depth: tree should be this depht
node_num: tree should have this much nodes
leaf_num: tree should have this much leafs
addr_in_f: relative address in file where I need to write node
addr_child_node: reltive address of child node
depth_now: current depth of three
num_leaf_now: current number of leafs
node_num_now: current number of nodes
cv[]: array with nodes
The probem is: function fwrite write node into file, but not into right address. I can't figure out where is a problem.

Before **fwrite** I use **rewind(...)** and **fseek(...)** to go on **addr_in_f**, and then print **ftell(...)** and **addr_in_f**, and they are the same value. Why then node isn't written in file on that position?

Thanks for help!

```
int create_node(int depth, int node_num, int leaf_num, int addr_in_f, int * addr_child_node, int * depth_now, int * num_leaf_now, int * node_num_now , NodeZI cv[]){
    NodeZI * czi;
    (*depth_now)++;
    if(*node_num_now < node_num){
        if(*depth_now == depth ){
            (*num_leaf_now)++;
            if((*num_leaf_now) <= leaf_num){
                czi.left.address= cv[(*num_leaf_now)-1].left.address;
                czi.left.key = cv[(*num_leaf_now)-1].left.key ;
                czi.right.address= cv[(*num_leaf_now)-1].right.address;
                czi.right.key = cv[(*num_leaf_now)-1].right.key ;
                FILE * file = fopen(naz_akt_dat, "ab");
                if(file == NULL){
                     printf("EROR!!!");

                }
                rewind(file);
                if(fseek(file,addr_in_f, SEEK_CUR)){
                     printf("ERR!!!");

                }
                printf("\ntell: %d, rel_addr: %d", ftell(file),addr_in_f);
                fwrite(czi, sizeof(NodeZI), 1, file);
                if(fwrite(czi, sizeof(NodeZI), 1, file)!=1){
                    printf("CAN'T WRITE!!!" );
                }

                fclose(file);
                (*node_num_now)++;
                (*depth_now)--;

                return czi.left.key ;      
            }else{
                (*depth_now)--;
                return -1;
            }
        }else if((*depth_now) < depth ){
            *addr_child_node= *addr_child_node+ sizeof(NodeZI);
            czi.left.address= *addr_child_node;
            int x = create_node(depth , node_num, leaf_num, *addr_child_node, addr_child_node, depth_now, num_leaf_now, node_num_now, cv);
            if(x == -1){
                czi.left.address= -1;
            }
            czi.left.key = x;
            *addr_child_node = *addr_child_node + sizeof(NodeZI);
            czi.right.address= *addr_child_node;
            x = create_node(depth , node_num, leaf_num, *addr_child_node, addr_child_node, depth_now, num_leaf_now, node_num_now, cv);

            czi.right.key = x;
            if(x == -1){
               czi.right.address= -1;
            }

            FILE * file = fopen(naz_akt_dat, "ab");
            rewind(file);
            fseek(file, addr_in_f, SEEK_CUR);

            if(fwrite(czi, sizeof(NodeZI), 1, file)==1){
                printf("CAN'T WRITE!!!");
            }

            fclose(file);
            (*node_num_now)++;
            (*depth_now)--;
            return czi.left.key ;

        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }else{
        czi.left.key = -1;
        czi.left.address= -1;
        czi.right.key = -1;
        czi.right.address= -1;
        (*depth_now)--;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you consider having your `FILE *` being an argument of your recursive function, instead of opening and closing it within it each time ?

Comment: Well.. writing a file from recursive function is a *bad* idea. Better generate your data structure (tree) and traverse it using some reconstructable traverse methods (http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/make-a-binary-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traveral/)

Comment: In `if(fwrite(czi, sizeof(NodeZI), 1, file)==1) { printf("CAN'T WRITE!!!"); }` shouldn't that test be `!=1`? Function `fwrite` returns the number of items written to file, and you asked for 1 item to be written of that size.

Comment: Is it necessary that you write to a file immediately whenever a new node is created (usually a tree is build up in memory and - when ready - flushed to a file)? What is the reason for mixing up transient and persistent memory that way?

Comment: the location in a file has no relationship to location in memory.  Strongly suggest when writing to the file to serialize the data including replacing each address pointer in the data with some kind of 'code' that indicates its' relative location in the tree

Comment: the posted code does not compile,  Amongst other things, like missing the needed `#include` statements, it is missing the definition of NodeZi